# Parsing a yaml object in Go which contains a struct

Tags: go, yaml

I have the following yaml:

```
segmentforward: ""
segmentbackward: ""
listforward: ""
promptready: "➜"

enabledhooks: ["alert"]

enabledsegments: ["host", "path", "python_env", "aws", "git", "filler", "command", "timestamp", "newline", "prompt_ready"]

hostsegment: { fgcolor: 250, bgcolor: 238 }
pathsegment: { fgcolor: 15, bgcolor: 31 }
pythonenvsegment: { fgcolor: 15, bgcolor: 22 }
awssegment: { fgcolor: 172, bgcolor: 238 }
gitsegment: { fgcolor: 238, bgcolor: 148 }
fillersegment: { fgcolor: 251, bgcolor: 251 }
commandsegment: { fgcolor: 238, bgcolor: 250 }
timestampsegment: { fgcolor: 250, bgcolor: 238 }
promptreadysegment: { fgcolor: 238, bgcolor: 251 }
```

I'm trying to parse this yaml with the following go code:

```
package config

import (
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type Config struct {
    SegmentForward string
    SegmentBackward string
    ListForward string
    PromptReady string
    EnabledHooks []string
    EnabledSegments []string
    HostSegment struct {
      FgColor int
      BgColor int
    }
}

func LoadConfig(path string) (config Config) {

    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }

    err = yaml.Unmarshal(data, &config)
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }

    return config
}
```

But this gives me the error:

```
panic: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 18: cannot unmarshal !!map into string

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x3364c0, 0xc42014a9c0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.4/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1
github.com/brujoand/sbp/config.LoadConfig(0x3b7138, 0x23, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /opt/go/src/github.com/brujoand/sbp/config/config.go:30 +0x12d
main.main()
    /opt/go/src/github.com/brujoand/sbp/main.go:18 +0x50
```

What I want here is to be able to reference these segments directly without looking up a map. And then have the same kind of fields within each segment. I'm aware that my namings in the Yaml isn't great (sorry about that), but right now I'm trying to understand how to access the fields in a simple way.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/NX5qQhHZFu - this works for me. Make sure your YAML is well-formed.

Comment: Thanks! I copied your version of the yaml over mine. And now it works. I tried to diff them but couldn't find any difference. Very weird, but problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This yaml can get unmarshaled into this perfectly (since you do not want to use a map):

```
type Config struct {
    SegmentForward  string
    SegmentBackward string
    ListForward     string
    PromptReady     string
    EnabledHooks    []string
    EnabledSegments []string

    HostSegment, PathSegment, PythonEnvSegment, AWSSegment, GitSegment  segment
    FillerSegment, CommandSegment, TimestampSegment, PromptReadySegment segment
}

type segment struct {
    FgColor int
    BgColor int
}
```